# Set colour to text in Android activity?

Tags: android, text, colors

I would like to set a red colour text in my app, but I don't know how.

Please provide references. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want it to set in XML layout then use:

```
<TextView 
 ...
 ...
 android:textColor="#FF0000" >
 </TextView>
```

If you want to set programmatically then use:

```
textview.setTextColor(Color.RED);
//textview must be defined in your class
```

Answer (score 3):

Read the docs for `TextView`, specifically for [`textColor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3atextColor).

Answer (score 2):

Use the following in your `xml` where you want to change the color to red and by using the other hexacode of color you can change to any other color. This is an example to set the color to red:

```
android:textColor="#FF0000"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your layout:

```
<TextView>
  ....
  textColor="red"
  ....
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a [custom style resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html) which uses an [Android Theme](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml) as a parent then override the text colors as defined in the Android theme.xml. Reference this new style in your [AndroidManifest.xml's application tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#theme).